# Make a animation or transition effect whenever element is appearing on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an animation or transition effect when the elements is appearing on user's screen **every time**.

Now I am using js Intersection Observer API.

```js
const options = {
  threshold: 0.25
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  detect, options
);

document.querySelectorAll('.grid').forEach(i => observer.observe(i));


function detect(elem) {
  for (let e of elem) {
    e.isIntersecting ? e.target.style.animation = 'transition 1s linear' : 
      e.target.style.animation = 'none';
     
  }
}
```

```css
.grid{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
margin-bottom:50px;


}
@keyframes transition{
  from{
  opacity:0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
<div class='grid'></div>
```

But is there any way to achieve this using pure css?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think CSS will do this alone - it doesn't 'know' when something enters the viewport. It could do various effects by having fixed elements at the bottom and top under which the elements emerge, but it won't look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an animation run on each page refresh, without any JS, but to only play it when the user scrolls to a certain section of the page, i'm afraid Intersection Observer is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to detect events like scrolling or detecting that item appeared on the screen in CSS